# pydev debugger does not stop in breakpoint

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, pydev

I'm using PyCharm Professional to debug Google App Engine project.
I configured debug configuration as appear in the official [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-appengineserver.html)

The working directory is set to the project path and configured to add the source roots and content roots to `PYTHONPATH`

The project run, but when I try to use breakpoints I get this error:

```
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /path/to/my/file.py (will have no effect)
```

I checked the file path and the file exist

Comment: Is it possible the file is symlinked?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the first time I run the debug it worked.
I'll check it

Comment: Yes. I remove the `symlinked` and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is likely symlinked. The debugger isn't able to follow symlinks.